# Why does the safe area not cover the width of the screen on iPad Pro 12.9"

Tags: ios, xcode, safearealayoutguide

For some reason, on 12.9" but not the other sizes, the safe area does not extend to the width of the screen.  Why is that?  And if I want something to extend to the full width of the screen, what is the best way to do that?  I've tried constraining to the superview, and that doesn't work.  Any ideas on what to do about this, or (best case) how to make the safe area extend to the full width of the screen on the iPad Pro 12.9", would be great.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question is false. As these screen shots show, a view pinned to the safe area at left and right reaches the edge of the screen on the iPad Pro 12.9 inch.

Instead of asking why the safe area is not the width of the screen, you should be asking what *you* are doing wrong such that your view is not as wide as the screen. You did not provide enough information with *this* question, though, to allow us to answer that one.

[image]

[image]